# How to start a program when CPU percent reaches X

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, worker-process

I have been having very intermittent problems with an ASP.NET v 4.0 application happens maybe ever 4 days, what happens is the CPU will spike to 75% and sometimes is will run fine until the end of the day sometimes it will steadily grow to 100%

Then I have to reboot the server.

I have followed every guide on "What to do when worker process is at 100% CPU" and I know which worker process it is, which application pool it is. All i can do is find the process and kill it or recycle the app pool and that will sometimes help.

What i do not know is what is going on, on the system at that moment when CPU goes to 75%.

I wondering is there a way i can start procmon when CPU hits say 50% and run for 2 minutes, then shut down and save the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never did it, but easiest way would be by using alert in perfmon.

As you can see below, you can run a script when the action happen.

> Select the Action tab, shown in Figure 3-18. You can now specify any
>   of the following actions to happen when an alert is triggered:
>        Log An Entry In The Application Event Log Creates log entries for alerts.
>
> Send A Network Message To Sends a network message to the computer specified.
>
> > Run This Program Sets the complete file path of a program or script to run when the alert occurs.

More info [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726968.aspx) to set the alert

after in your script you could run it that way;

```
procmon /Quiet /Minimized /BackingFile log.PML
TIMEOUT /T 120
procmon /Terminate
```